# Counting the number of browser windows opened by Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, c#

Is there a way to get a list of opened browser windows using Selenium? I want to use this to count the number of open browsers within a test.

Answer (score 3):

`IWebDriver` has the method `WindowHandles`. The method returns a collection. So you can use the size of the collection to get the number of open windows.

- [IWebDriver Interface](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver.htm)
- [IWebDriver.WindowHandles Property](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/P_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver_WindowHandles.htm)

I am not so familiar with C#, but in Java this works:
`driver.getWindowHandles().size();`

In C# this should work:
`Driver.WindowHandles.Count;`

Comment: The Java example is missing an s. It should be `driver.getWindowHandles().size();`

Comment: @DustinN. Thank you for pointing this out. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example to count the number of opened windows is go to www.rediff.com
you will get atleat 2-opened windows.
1 - rediff.com Home Page.
2 - Ad window.

below is the simple code to count the no of opened wind and get windowhandle code.

```
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("G:\\Selenium_Csharp\\Jar\\chromedriver_win32");
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.rediff.com");

        String originalWindowHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
        Console.WriteLine("original Window handles are: " + originalWindowHandle);
        Console.WriteLine("Title of original Page:" + driver.Title);

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<string> windowHandles = driver.WindowHandles;

        Console.WriteLine("Count the no. of opened windows: "+windowHandles.Count);
        foreach (String window in windowHandles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(window);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For C# - `Driver.WindowHandles.Count;`

count starts with 1.

You can use condition `Driver.WindowHandles.Count=0` to handle any exception related to Browser operation if none of the browser is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to find the number of windows gets opened

```
int i=1;

for (string eachwindow : allwindow)

{

driver.switchTo().window(eachwindow);

System.out.println(eachwindow);

i++;

}

System.out.println(i); //displays the count of windows gets opened
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `getWindowHandles()` method. For example:

```
Set<String> winHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();

int numberOfWindows = windowHandles.size();
```